# How to generate invoice and slipping slip

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice

we are using Magento Marketplace in my website. I want to generate Invoice slip and shipping slip in front end seller dashboard. I used below code

```
public function saveTrackingNumberAction(){
            try{
                if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
                    $orderid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
                    $trackingid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('tracking_id');
                    $carrier=$this->getRequest()->getParam('carrier');
                    $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
                    $partnerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
                    $items=array();
                    $shippingAmount=0;
                    $trackingsdata=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                                     ->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                                     ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',array('eq'=>$partnerid));
                    $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($itemid);
                    foreach($trackingsdata as $tracking){
                        $tracking->setTrackingNumber($trackingid);
                        $tracking->setCarrierName($carrier);
                        $tracking->save();
                        $product_name="";
                        $shippingAmount=$tracking->getShippingCharges();
                        $items=explode(',',$tracking->getItemIds());
                        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
                            if(in_array($item->getId(),$items)){
                                $product_name =$product_name.$product->getName()." ,";
                            }
                        }

                        $product_name = $product->getName();
                        $to = $order->getCustomerEmail();

                        $emailTemp = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('trackingnopartner');
                        $emailTempVariables = array();              
                        $adminEmail=Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $order->getIncrementId();
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $product_name;
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar3'] = $order->getIncrementId();
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar4'] = $trackingid;
                        $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);
                        $emailTemp->setSenderName('Admin');
                        $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
                        $emailTemp->send($to,'Admin',$emailTempVariables);
                    }

                        /**/
                    $itemsarray = $this->_getItemQtys($order,$items);

                    if(count($itemsarray)>0){
                        if($order->canInvoice()) { 
                            $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($itemsarray['data']);
                            $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
                            $invoice->setShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
                            $invoice->setSubtotal($itemsarray['subtotal']);
                            $invoice->setBaseSubtotal($itemsarray['baseSubtotal']);
                            $invoice->setGrandTotal($itemsarray['subtotal']+$shippingAmount);
                            $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($itemsarray['subtotal']+$shippingAmount);
                            $invoice->register();

                            $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                        ->addObject($invoice)
                                        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
                            $transactionSave->save();
                            $order->sendNewOrderEmail()->addStatusHistoryComment(
                                Mage::helper('mpshippingmanager')->__('Notified customer about invoice #%s.', $invoice->getId())
                            )
                            ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
                            ->save();
                            $seller_invoice_id = $invoice->getId();
                        }else{
                            if($order->hasInvoices()) {
                                foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) { 
                                    foreach ($inv->getAllItems() as $item) { 
                                        $product_id = $item->getProductId();
                                        $seller_pro_coll=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()
                                                                ->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$product_id))
                                                                ->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$partnerid));
                                        foreach ($seller_pro_coll as $value) {
                                            if($value->getMageproductid()){
                                                $seller_invoice_id = $inv->getId();
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        $shipment = false;              
                        $shipmentId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('shipment_id');         
                        $orderId = $orderid;    
                        if($shipmentId){
                            $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipmentId);
                        }elseif($orderId){
                            $order  = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
                            if (!$order->getId()) {
                                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order no longer exists.'));
                                return false;
                            }
                            if($order->getForcedDoShipmentWithInvoice()){
                                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot do shipment for the order separately from invoice.'));
                                return false;
                            }
                            if(!$order->canShip()){
                                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot do shipment for the order.'));
                                return false;
                            }

                            $savedQtys = $this->_getItemQtys($order,$items);
                            $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($savedQtys['data']);
                        }
                        $shipment->register();
                        $comment = '';
                        $shipment->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(1);
                        $responseAjax = new Varien_Object();
                        $isNeedCreateLabel = isset($data['create_shipping_label']) && $data['create_shipping_label'];
                        if ($isNeedCreateLabel && true) {
                            $responseAjax->setOk(true);
                        }
                        $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
                        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                    ->addObject($shipment)->addObject($shipment->getOrder())->save();
                        /*sale list status update*/
                        $partnerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
                        $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid', array('eq' => $partnerid))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid', array('eq' => $orderid));
                        foreach($collection as $saleproduct){
                            $saleproduct->setCpprostatus(1);
                            $saleproduct->save();
                        }
                        /*sale list status update*/
                        $shipment->sendEmail(1, $comment);
                        $shipmentCreatedMessage = $this->__('The shipment has been created.');
                        $labelCreatedMessage    = $this->__('The shipping label has been created.');
                        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($isNeedCreateLabel ? $shipmentCreatedMessage . ' ' . $labelCreatedMessage
                            : $shipmentCreatedMessage); 

                        $trackingcol1=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('seller_id ',array('in'=>$partnerid));
                        $courrier="custom";
                        foreach($trackingcol1 as $row) {
                            if($shipment->getId() != '') { 
                                $row->setShipmentId($shipment->getId());
                                $row->setInvoiceId($seller_invoice_id)->save();
                                $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
                                 ->setShipment($shipment)
                                 ->setData('title',  $row->getCarrierName())
                                 ->setData('number', $row->getTrackingNumber())
                                 ->setData('carrier_code',  $courrier)
                                 ->setData('order_id', $shipment->getData('order_id'))
                                 ->save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $trackingcol=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('tracking_number',array('eq'=>''));
                    if(count($trackingcol)==0){
                        $trackingcol=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('tracking_number',array('eq'=>'canceled'));
                        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
                        if(count($trackingcol)==0){
                            $product_order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
                            $order->setStatus('complete');
                            $order->save();
                        }else{
                            $order->cancel();
                            $order->save();
                        }
                        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                        $historyItem = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_history_collection')
                            ->getUnnotifiedForInstance($order, Mage_Sales_Model_Order::HISTORY_ENTITY_NAME);
                        if ($historyItem) {
                            $historyItem->setIsCustomerNotified(1);
                            $historyItem->save();
                        }       
                    }
                    if(count($trackingsdata)==0)
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("This order doesn't contain Tracking Number..");
                    else
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Tracking Number successfully Assign..');
                    $this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/invoice/id/',array('id'=>$orderid));
                }
            }catch(Exception $e){
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/invoice/id/',array('id'=>$orderid));
            }
        }
```

**.phtml**

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/savetrackingnumber')?>" id="shipping-form" method="post">
<div class="shipping_top">
<span class="shipping_service"><?php echo $helper->__('Carrier');?></span>
<span class="row_total"><?php echo $helper->__('Tracking Number');?></span>
</div>
<div class="items">
<input class="required-entry" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>" name="order_id"/>
<div class="wk_item">
<span class="carrier"><input class="required-entry carrier" value="<?php echo $tracking->getCarrierName(); ?>" <?php echo $disabled;?> type="text" name="carrier"/></span>
<span class="row_total wk_track_input"><input class="required-entry" value="<?php echo $tracking->getTrackingNumber(); ?>" <?php echo $disabled;?> type="text" name="tracking_id"/></span>
<?php if(count($shipping_coll)): ?>
<?php if($item_status=="Ordered"): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/cancelorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
<button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?></span></span>
</button>
</a>
<?php endif;  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($item_status=="Ordered"||$item_status=="Invoiced"){?>
<button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Save Tracking Number') ?>" type="submit" id="save_butn" >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Save Tracking Number') ?></span></span>
</button>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

It's working fine but my problem is order status automatically change complete. I don't want to change any order status

Answer (score 0):

config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Invoicer>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Custom_Invoicer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custom_invoicer>
                <class>Custom_Invoicer_Model</class>
            </custom_invoicer>
        </models>        
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <custom_invoicer_automatically_complete_order>
                        <class>custom_invoicer/observer</class>
                        <method>automaticallyInvoiceShipCompleteOrder</method>
                    </custom_invoicer_automatically_complete_order>
                </observers>                
            </sales_order_save_after>
        </events>        
    </global>
</config>
```

observer.php

```
<?php
class Custom_Invoicer_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_after', $this->_getEventData());
     * protected $_eventPrefix = 'sales_order';
     * protected $_eventObject = 'order';
     * event: sales_order_save_after
     */
    public function automaticallyInvoiceShipCompleteOrder($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq'=>$order->getId()));
        $orders->getSelect()->limit(1);  

        if ((int)$orders->count() !== 0) {
            return $this;
        }

        if ($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW) {

            try {
                if(!$order->canInvoice()) {
                    $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Custom_Invoicer: Order cannot be invoiced.', false);
                    $order->save();  
                }

                //START Handle Invoice
                $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();

                $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
                $invoice->register();

                $invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(true);          
                $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
                $invoice->sendEmail(true, '');
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically INVOICED by Custom_Invoicer.', false);

                $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                    ->addObject($invoice)
                    ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

                $transactionSave->save();

                //~ //END Handle Invoice
 //~ 
                //~ //START Handle Shipment
                $shipment = $order->prepareShipment();
                $shipment->register();

                $order->setIsInProcess(true);
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically SHIPPED by Custom_Invoicer.', false);

                $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                    ->addObject($shipment)
                    ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                    ->save();
                //~ //END Handle Shipment
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Custom_Invoicer: Exception occurred during automaticallyInvoiceShipCompleteOrder action. Exception message: '.$e->getMessage(), false);
                $order->save();
            }                
        }

    return $this;        
    }
}
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: already i am using extension i don't want to override

Comment: in code everything is working fine i want to remove order status only